# How to add filter_sensitive_data object in VCR Cassette JSON file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, vcr

Below is my VCR configuration file

```rb
VCR.configure do |c|
  c.cassette_library_dir = 'spec/fixture/vcr_cassettes'
  c.hook_into :webmock
  c.configure_rspec_metadata!
  c.default_cassette_options = {
    serialize_with: :json
  }
  c.preserve_exact_body_bytes do true end
  c.filter_sensitive_data('<WSDL>') { Rails.application.credentials.client[:rspec_url] }
end
```

I have created **WSDL** object and I want to add this object in the below VCR cassettes JSON file:

```
{ "http_interactions": [
  { "request": { "method": "get", "uri": **wsdl** object, 
     "body": { "encoding":
```

How to `add filter_sensitive_data` object in VCR Cassette JSON file?